# Cannot read property 'type' of undefined | useRouter React Native

Tags: react-native, expo-router

Using `FirebaseAuth` I have an `AuthContext` that I wrap around my app to detect if a user is present or not.

If a user is found I want to replace the route, using `expo-router` however, I am getting the error

> Cannot read property 'type' of undefined

When trying to replace the route.

### AuthContext

```
export const AuthContext = createContext({
  user: null,
  loading: true,
});

export const AuthProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const [user, setUser] = useState(null);
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);

  const handleSignOut = async () => {
    await signOut(FIREBASE_AUTH);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    const unsubscribe = onAuthStateChanged(FIREBASE_AUTH, (user) => {
      setUser(user);
      setLoading(false);
    });

    return () => unsubscribe();
  }, [user]);

  const value = {
    user,
    loading,
    handleSignOut,
  };
  return <AuthContext.Provider value={value}>{children}</AuthContext.Provider>;
```

### Index

```
const Splash = () => {
  const router = useRouter();
  const { user, loading } = useContext(AuthContext);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (user) {
      console.log("USER:", user.uid);
      // router.replace("(tabs)/home"); //  IF UNCOMMENTED Cannot read property 'type' of undefined
    } else {
      console.log("USER NOT FOUND");
      // router.replace("(auth)/onboard"); // IF UNCOMMENTED Cannot read property 'type' of undefined
    }
  }, [user, loading]);

  return (
    <SafeAreaView>
      <Text>LOADING...</Text>
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
};

export default function Root() {
  return (
    <AuthProvider>
      <Splash />
    </AuthProvider>
  );
}
```